# How do I calculate the AIC for a distribution in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have:

```
from scipy import stats
data = stats.gamma.rvs(2, loc=1.5, scale=2, size=100000)
```

so I do a fit on that

```
fitted_params = scipy.stats.gamma.fit(data)
```

how do I calculate the AIC from that?
`AIC = 2*k - 2*ln(L)` where k is the number of parameters fitted and L is the maximum log likelihood function

```
k = len(fitted_params)
aic = 2*k - 2*(logLik)
```

`logLik` would be ?

I found this snippet:

```
logLik = -np.sum( stats.norm.logpdf(data, loc=yPred, scale=sd) )
```

from [Maximum Likelihood Estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718034/maximum-likelihood-estimate-pseudocode)

so is my function going to be:

```
# calc SD of fitted distribution
sd = std(loc=fitted_params[1], scale=fitted_params[2])

# sample values from fitted dist same length as original data array
yPred = rvs(fitted_params[0], loc=fitted_params[1], scale=fitted_params[2], size=len(data), random_state=None)

# calc the log likelihood 
logLik = -np.sum( stats.gamma.logpdf(data, loc=yPred, scale=sd) )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likelihood is really the probability of observing the data given the parameters.  Hence, if you have some parameter values, i.e. your fitted values, then the likelihood is probability of the data, where the density is parameterized with the fitted values.

Hence, what you're doing is almost correct.  Since you sampled from a gamma distribution, you should also calculate the likelihood using that distribution.  I.e. instead of

```
logLik = -np.sum( stats.norm.logpdf(data, loc=yPred, scale=sd) )
```

do

```
logLik = np.sum( stats.gamma.logpdf(data, fitted_params[0], loc=fitted_params[1], scale=fitted_params[2]) )
```

Then you just use your AIC equation to get that.

Comment: Guess the parameters passed to logpdf function can be simplified as stats.gamma.logpdf(data, *fitted_params)

Comment: as @KevinZhu said, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588602/calculating-loglikelihood-of-distributions-in-python) answer for updated log likelihood