# Calculating loglikelihood of distributions in Python

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, log-likelihood

What is an easy way **to calculate the loglikelihood of any distribution** fitted to data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python)

Comment: I use some methods of that post indeed, but the notion of loglikelihood is not mentioned there nor could I find it elsewhere on SO.

Answer (score 3):

*Solution by OP.*

Python has 82 standard distributions which can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) and in `scipy.stats.distributions`

Suppose you find the parameters such that the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)(pdf) fits the data as follows:

```
dist = getattr(stats.stats, 'distribution name')
params = dist.fit(data)
```

Then since it is a standard distribution included in the SciPy library, the pdf and logpdf can be found and used very easily in the following way:

```
LLH = dist.logpdf(data,*params).sum()
```

Note that that this corresponds to the loglikelihood function defined [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Log-LikelihoodFunction.html)